# "Sudo" prefixed command doesn't work; without sudo does.

Tags: sudo, io-redirection, process-substitution

I suspect this has been answered before, but I don't know what this is called, so I can't really search for it.

How come this works :

```
$ grep H=p <(udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0)
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.5.2:1.0
```

But this doesn't ? :

```
$ sudo grep H=p <(udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0)
grep: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

Nevermind the fact that sudo isn't necessary in this case, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell is replacing `<(udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0)` with `/dev/fd/63` (after dup'ing the read end of the pipe to fd 63) before running the command. However, sudo closes all file descriptors greater than 2 by default. You can change this by using sudo's `--close-from` flag, but there's a better way:

> sudo bash -c 'grep H=p <(udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0)'

Comment: Neat, thank you. 
Of course I'll have to practice with it to really learn/understand it in time !